# How to know user come to specific location in iOS ? [Neither in Background nor in Foreground]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location

I have users's current location. And i can match in radius where user inside loop or not.

I have did in Foreground and Background of app. But i wants to do in terminated app. when user near by my specific points how to pop up alert once enter my zone  ?!!?

Comment: I think it is not possible, because when ios app is terminated then app code is not in running state.

Comment: how do you expect your app _running_ when that has been _terminated_?

Comment: @holex yes, that is case. But Is there any possible way to achieve this ? By any other Push alert !!

Comment: you can try to create an extension for your app... hypothetically you can do that, but how frequently iOS invoked your extension when the location is updated and your extension is not active...? that is something for you to try out – but the alert-controller is not available in extension for sure to throw a popup just like that.

Answer (score 0):

**For Background or Terminate state of Application**

```
/*
 *  startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
 *
 *  Discussion:
 *      Start monitoring significant location changes.  The behavior of this service is not affected by the desiredAccuracy
 *      or distanceFilter properties.  Locations will be delivered through the same delegate callback as the standard
 *      location service.
 *
 */
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
open func startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

**Use CLRegion for GeoFencing** - To track weather user come inside of the region and went away of the region

```
  let region = CLCircularRegion(center: geotification.coordinate, radius: geotification.radius, identifier: geotification.identifier)

  region.notifyOnEntry = (geotification.eventType == .onEntry)
  region.notifyOnExit = !region.notifyOnEntry
```

Comment: ok, i will receive update in delegate, How to trigger alert if app is neither background nor foreground.. Will it work !!

Comment: Yes, You just to startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges in Background state. Have to trigger a Local notification to notify users.

Comment: neither background nor foreground.. App is terminated.

Comment: While you came to foreground means have to stopMonitoringSignificantLocation and startLocationUpdation